# In storyboard, Popoverview don't receive delegation

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard, xcode4.2

I'm working sample app by storyboard.
When made popoverview, I used the way - '`Embed in navigation controller`'.

But I'm getting a big trouble of `delegate` usage.
It's that don't delegate to popover view's.

[image: Xcode - Embedded Menu]

[ViweController.m]

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PopRootViewController"]){

        NSLog(@"[segue destinationViewController] :%@", [segue destinationViewController]); 

        rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];              
        rootViewController.delegate = (id)self; 

        NSLog(@"%@---%@---%@", rootViewController.delegate, self, rootViewController); 
    }
}

-(void)didTap22 {

    NSLog(@"delegate step 1 success!! "); 
}
```

The result of this source like this :

```
[segue destinationViewController] :<UINavigationController: 0x88660a0>
<ViewController: 0x6b795e0>---<ViewController: 0x6b795e0>---<RootViewController: 0x6b7da60>
```

but [RootViewController] don't receive the delegation.

[RootViewController.m]

```
@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize items, delegate;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     .... 
    self.items = mutableFetchResults;

    NSLog(@"333333..... %@, ....... %@", self.delegate, self); 

}
```

results :

```
333333..... (null), ....... <RootViewController: 0x8866520>
```

RootViewController's delegation is null.
I can't find solution about this.

Anybody help me, please!

Comment: Put a `NSLog(@"about to set delegate");` before the line `rootViewController.delegate = (id)self;`, that should explain it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand your comment. What is my fault?

Comment: It should show that viewWillAppear was already called when you set the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you didn't declare your delegate UIPopoverControllerDelegate in the class declaration of your view controller.

This line is suspicious:

```
 rootViewController.delegate = (id)self;
```

you don't need to cast self normally if you made the declaration I am mentioning.